# How can I avoid applying textures to a fragment in a shader when the surface normal is (0, 1, 0)?

Tags: shaders, glsl

I have a small GLSL shader with a vertex shader and a fragment shader. I want to avoid applying textures to faces that have a normal equal to `(0, 1, 0)`. Is this possible? These are my shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 120

varying vec2 UV;
varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{
  UV = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
  normal = gl_Normal;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 120

varying vec2 UV;
uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;

void main(void)
{
  gl_FragColor = texture(diffuseMap, UV);
}
```

Comment: How do you send your vertex and normal data to your shader?

Comment: can you elaborate why do you want to do this? maybe you are asking the wrong question

Comment: And what do you want to replace those fragments that you don't texture with? A solid color? A fully-transparent color?

Comment: @Basaa Using Ogre3D. No idea how. I have a material script with some textures

Comment: @concept3d I have to render some variable-sized boxes, and I want to render the sides and bottom with a normal texture, and the top part with the same texture but with some effects. The top texture has a normal with `y == 1` as it is pointing upwards

Comment: @JoshPetrie Some shaders effects, inverted colors, some transparency, etc.

Comment: @Pacha eventhough I did't fully understand what you are trying to do, I really believe this isn't the way to do it. What I think you should do, is using seperate draw calls with different shaders and textures. You don't even have to check for normal(0,1,0) just apply it for whatever objects you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an if-statement in the fragment shader and pass through the normal or a flag from the vertex shader.

Note that sampling of textures must be in uniform flow, i.e. outside of the if-statement.  Something like the following probably-not-legal-GLSL:

```
// vertex
in vec4 aPosition;
in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 vsNormal;

void main(void)
{
  gl_FragCoord = project_transform * aPosition;
  vsNormal = aNormal;
}

// pixel
in vec3 vsNormal;

void main(void)
{
   vec4 tex = texture2D(blah);
   vec4 color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);

   // depending on the input normal,
   // you should better normalize it in the fragment shader before you use it
   vec3 normal = normalize(vsNormal);
   float dotN = dot(vsNormal, vec3(0,1,0));

   if (dotN < 0.99)
     color *= tex;
   else
     really_simple_effect();

   gl_FragColor = color;
 }
```

Note that you want to deeply minimize the amount of code you use inside of any branch in a shader.  You might be best off simply rendering a 5-sided "cube" for the sides/bottom and then a separate plane for the top with two totally different materials/shaders.  Batch as much as you can (e.g. draw all the 5-sides parts in one go, then draw all the tops in a second go).

Comment: @Pacha that is the way to do it as you asked. But I still believe this is not the "correct" way to do it, checking if normal equals a certain value is far from ideal and will limit the use of the shader. I still think multiple draw calls are the way to go.

Comment: @Pacha also expect some unexpected failures because checking float with == and != is likely to fail sometimes, especially if you are calculating the normals.

Comment: @Pacha: I agree with concept3d.  You really want to do what I suggested in the last paragraph.  The == and != will likely work in the use case I think you're in but he's again right that you need to be wary floating-point imprecision depending on what you're doing.

Comment: I am using ranges though for floating points. (betweeen .99 and 1.01)

Comment: You still need to be careful.  Is decimal `.01` an appropriate range for you operations?  Calculating the safe epsilons for floating-point operations is a black art few know and you're generally better off finding approaches that don't need them at all.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Speaking of which - is epsilon defined in the GLSL/OpenGL spec, or is it implementation-dependent? Hmmm.

Comment: @DavidLively: neither.  GL sets minimum precision requirements and an implementation can vary within the bounds set by GL, but the correct epsilon is not directly based on precision, so epsilons are not specified anywhere since they depend on your code.